# Is there a way to send information from a Microsoft chatbot to a website depending on conversation result

Tags: javascript, html, azure, botframework, limesurvey

I use the Microsoft Bot Framework with Node.js to implement a chatbot. I try to use this chatbot within a "LimeSurvey"-Survey (you can use HTML code to integrate the bot into the survey, so you can basically assume it's a normal website). Depending on the result of the conversation, I want to show different information on this website. Let's say the conversation can have 10 different results. Is there any way I can communicate the conversation's "result" to the website and show different information depending on that? It would be sufficient to be able to send a number between 1 and 10 to the website. I can either use an iframe to integrate the bot or do it as you can see in the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
    <script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
        directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ secret: 'M_BOT_SECRET_FROM_AZURE_PORTAL' }),
        userID: 'YOUR_USER_ID'
      }, document.getElementById('webchat'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "conversation results". Reformulate and give us more examples of what you want to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

I hope you have setup the Chatbot using directline channel and it is in working condition.

To get the response from the bot, you can listen to the activity events of the directline channel.

```
const botConnection = new BotChat.DirectLine({
    domain: params['domain'],
    secret: <secret_key>,
    token: <any_params>,
    webSocket: params['webSocket'] && params['webSocket'] === 'true' // defaults to true
 });

  BotChat.App({
    bot: bot,
    botConnection: botConnection,
    user: user,
    locale: userDetail.userLanguage,
  }, document.getElementById('chatBot'));


    //listening to activities sent and received
    botConnection.activity$
    .subscribe(function(activity){
        if(activity.type == "message" && activity.text == <some_response_from_bot>){
            //your logic to show on the web page
        }
    });
```

So, within the listener you can trace all the activity messages and take action on what to do. In your case show different results depending on the conversation.

I recommend you reading these-

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-receive-activities?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Comment: The [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) implementation has been redesigned and is moving away from `BotChat.app()`. While it is still able to be used, best practice is to send to/receive from a bot using the WebChat.renderWebChat method.

Answer (score 1):

To show information on a webpage that depends on the result of a conversation, you need to configure your bot to send activities that contain channelData with the result and add a listener for the activities that contain a result to your WebChat component.

First, in your bot, when you get to the end of your conversation flow and have the result, send an activity to the user with a `name` attribute and `channelData` that contains the result. The  `name` attribute will be used to filter all the incoming activities on the conversation side. The code in your bot should look like this:

```
await turnContext.sendActivity({
    name: 'result',
    channelData: {
        payload: {
            result: turnContext.activity.text
        }
    }
});
```

Now, we are going to add a custom middleware to our WebChat component to handle incoming activities. When activities are received, we can filter them by the `name` attribute and then perform the correct action based on the result value from the `channelData`. Your WebChat should look like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.botframework.com/botframework-webchat/latest/webchat.js"></script>
<div id="webchat" role="main"></div>
<script>
  (async function () {
    // To talk to your bot, you should use the token exchanged using your Direct Line secret.
    // You should never put the Direct Line secret in the browser or client app.
    // It is being included here only for simplicity
    // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-direct-line-3-0-authentication

    const res = await fetch('https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/tokens/generate', {
              method: 'POST',
              headers: {
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + secret
              },
          json: true
        });
    const { token } = await res.json();

    // We are adding a new middleware to customize the behavior of DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY.
    const store = window.WebChat.createStore(
      {},
      ({ dispatch }) => next => action => {
        if (action.type === 'DIRECT_LINE/INCOMING_ACTIVITY') {

          // Get activity from action
          const { activity } = action.payload;

          // Check if the name attribute in the activity is `result`
          if (activity.name === 'result'){

              // Get result from channel data
              const { result } = activity.channelData.payload;

              switch (result) {
                case 'result1':
                  alert(result)
                  // TODO: Action 1
                  break;
                case 'result2':
                  // TODO: Action 2
                  break;
                default:
                  // TODO: Default Action
            }
          }
        } 
        return next(action);
      }
    );

    window.WebChat.renderWebChat({
      directLine: window.WebChat.createDirectLine({ token }),
      // We will use a custom version of Redux store, which we added middleware to handle backchannel messages.
      store
    }, document.getElementById('webchat'));

    document.querySelector('#webchat > *').focus();
  })().catch(err => console.error(err));
</script>
```

Please note, you shouldn't store your Direct Line secret in the browser or client app. It is included here only for simplicity. I would also recommend looking at the [BotFramework-WebChat Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) - particularly sample [number 15](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/15.backchannel-piggyback-on-outgoing-activities).

Hope this helps!

Comment: What is the recommended way to store the direct line secret?